# How to Filter Events by Account Properties in Salesforce Events?

Tags: account, event, calendar

I am having some trouble trying to create a list view filter in the Events object in Salesforce.  I am trying to find a field that is on the Account object to use in my filter on the Events object list view.  I see that a lookup is done to an Account on the Events, but the specific field I need is not appearing in the list view filter selection list.

Is there a way to create a new field on the Event object?  I don't see a button to create new fields on this object.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

List Views don't allow filtering to be done on parent fields. What you'll need to do is create a formula field on `Event` such as `AccountFieldX__c` which is defined as `Account.AccountFieldX__c`

Events support custom fields - you create them on the `Activity` object. `Activity` custom fields are available in both `Task` and `Event` Sobjects but you can choose which layout to show them on (if any)